# Mips, store byte into register causes exception

Tags: assembly, mips

Since I didnt find anything that helped me fixing my problem Im just going to ask myself, I have the following assembly(mips) code for example:

```
.data

.text
    main:

        li $t2, 'S'
        sb $t2, 0($t3)

        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

In my "original" program Im reading a String character for character, saving each one into a register until a " " (Space) appears, to get single words. Now loading byte for byte into a register $t1 works, checking if the read character is a "Space" (to stop loop) works too, but when I then want to store that byte as written above into another register (which should at the end contain the whole word) produces that error. Whats wrong? As far as I understood, the code above should store the byte contained in "$t2" into $t3 + 0" ? Thats at least what definitions and literature say.. and since a character is 1 byte, this should work? But I seem to misunderstand something and would be really happy about any hints or explanations

The error is `Exception occured at ...` and then the position of the line with `sb $t2, 0($t3)`

Then another error with `Bad address in data Stack read 0x0000...`

It works when I do this:

```
.data

    word:   .space 10
.text
    main:

        la $t1, word
        li $t2, 'S'

        sb $t2, 0($t1)

        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

But how do I get what I want without declaring something in the data segment? Error seems to appear because I want to store something into the adress $t3 + 0 while $t3 doesnt even have a valid adress

Comment: You write that you want to store a byte from one register to another. But as far as I recall that is not what `sb` does. It writes a byte to memory at address $t3+0 (in your case). So if $t3 doesn't hold a valid memory address, you have a problem.

Comment: It works when I allocate some space in the data segment (will edit the question to show you how), but I dont want to do that. Can I not "give" the register $t3 an adress without loading a declared word, array or whatever with "la $t3, array" or whatever?

Comment: The `sb` will use anything what it will find in `t3` as memory address. You may set it up even in some crazy style, no need to use `la`, but `sb` will not care, how you set up value of `t3`, it will simply take it as is, and use it as memory address. Whether it points to valid memory or not. Is the question how to write value in `t2` into `t3` (`move $t3, $t2`), or how to get temporary memory space (you can "allocate" some temporary space in "stack" memory by subtracting some fixed amount from `$sp`, and then "releasing" it by adding that value back to `$sp`, but it's still memory, like .data)

Comment: is this a simulator or real hardware?  in either case which.

Answer (score 1):

```
        sb $t2, 0($t3)
```

> the code above should store the byte contained in "$t2" into $t3 + 0

That's a bit weird usage of those terms, I'm not sure whether you are just using them in confusing way, or you even understand them wrongly, but I will try to explain what is IMO correct way to describe what this does.

That code line takes value of `t2` register, and stores it into computer memory at address `t3 + 0`. *"storing it into $t3 + 0"* description sounds to me like modifying the content of `t3` register, which it does NOT.

You can imagine it in head as two distinct chips (HW chips, not food), one being MIPS CPU. This one has 32 general(1) purpose registers, each being 32 bits wide, that's 1024 bits of information, stored directly in the CPU chip. When you use wording "storing into register", I imagine writing the information into one of the slots inside this 1024 bit array on CPU, being "addressed" by register name, like `$14` (having alias name `$t6`).

The other chip is the memory chip, which has only few transistors dedicated to some "logic" (picking up signals from address and data-bus-wires, and reading/storing value from correct memory bit cells according to the bus state), and 99% of it's transistors/cells are just memory cells storing one bit value (0 or 1, encoded in different electricity current). These are grouped by words (32 together forming single unit), and addressable by bytes (four 8 bit subpart of word element), i.e. each byte has distinct address in the memory chip.

To store value into memory with instruction `sb` you have to provide the byte value (the low 8 bits of `t2` register in your case), and memory address (whole 32 bits of `t3` register used as address value), then the CPU will set `t3` content to "address" part of bus, `t2` content to "data" part of bus, and signal the memory chip to do "store" operation with those. But you don't provide in your example `t3` with any value, so it will address some random computer memory (probably zero address, which is often used as `NULL` in higher languages, and thus by default it is often mapped as invalid memory address by the OS), which is off limits to you, and the `sb` instruction does crash on writing into illegal part of computer memory.

To remedy you have to specify where in memory you want to store the newly generated data, like you can reserve some space in `.data` segment (to have some memory for writing):

```
.data
word_buffer: .space 1000  # maximum possible word length is 1000 (including terminator value)
  # if you will overwrite 1001 bytes, you will overwrite following memory
```

Then you can set up `t3` to contain address of the first of the reserved 1000 bytes as:

```
    la $t3, word_buffer   # la = "load address" pseudo instruction
        # this will modify the "t3" content on the CPU chip, not memory
```

When using simulator like MARS/SPIM, you can check after compilation the symbol table to see where in memory the buffer is located, i.e. `word_buffer` symbol will have value like `0x00401000` or similar, that's the memory address which will used to modify memory content by `sb` instruction (also it means that `la` is basically alias of `li $t3, 0x00401000`, but using "la" has more readability for anyone reviewing your source about your original intent).

---

*1) I don't find them completely general-purpose, as `$0` aka `$zero` will always read as zero (even when you write other value into it), and few more have a bit special implicit usage, like `$sp`, but about ~28-29 of them are general and equal in any usage you wish.

---

EDIT: about your question edit

Still not clear what you mean, as you now realize yourself the `t3 + 0` is invalid memory address. So you must either to decide which part of memory you will use:

- two common choices are `.data` segment, and stack memory, you can also pick up the video memory (MARS simulator has plugin for bitmap display, can be configured to use some shared general memory around `$gp` address, which is provided by the MARS "OS"), or you can use "OS" API to reserve some memory dynamically from the "heap" memory reserve the OS is managing.
- or you may use the register storage itself (bits stored inside CPU, not in memory), then the answer to your question is simple `move $t3, $t2`, which will copy value of `t2` into `t3` (whole 32 bits).

If you want to operate with bytes only (8 bits) in registers, you have to apply correct masks (by `andi` usually, or shifting old values in desired way to make space for new bits), and merge register bits with `or` (in some cases also `add` and similar may be desirable for value merging, if you know, what you are doing), to build up the 32 bit content of register in a way you desire (like for example having four different 8 bit sub-parts stored in single register).

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the answer. Im not good at writing correctly what I mean when it comes to programming and technical details (I should better learn to) but I did mean the "right" thing. But still I didnt know the other details, that explanation really gave me a better understanding. I will probably have to go the way with specifying space in .data since there doesnt seem to be a way to give $t3 (in this example) a valid adress in another way? In the above code at least, without adding something in the data segment

Comment: the information must live somewhere. You have only 32 registers on CPU, each only 32 bit wide, so in your task (info from other questions) you can store in `t3` itself only up to four letters at most (in ASCII encoding ... in UTF32 encoding it would be possible to store only single letter in `t3`). So you need memory storage for longer words, or operate over several register (please don't, that would lead to quite hairy code). When you write your app, you are free to reserve few megabytes of memory in `.data` segment, and you can use few kilobytes of "stack" given to you by OS (`$sp` address).

Comment: I.e. you can do `addi $sp, $sp, -400` (EDIT: minus 400!! stack grows downward) - to reserve 400 bytes of memory in "stack" (I keep writing "stack" because there's nothing magical/special about it, it's just another part of computer memory, mapped at different addresses than `.data`, but still ordinary computer memory). and then `move $t3, $sp` to set `t3` to point to that newly allocated 400 bytes... after you are done with it, you can restore `$sp` to point back by `addi $sp, $sp, 400`. Keep using multiplies of 4 for such stack manipulation, to keep value in `sp` word-aligned all the time.

Comment: @jfordummies you may also want to re-read through your initial course/notes now (and your earlier problems), with your new insight, maybe now it will all make lot more sense, and you will pick up the new details you missed at start, making your life much easier with further development. :) And yes, you must be absolutely exact in assembly, the computer will not guess anything, it will blindly do exactly what you wrote, and that's pretty much the language/thinking way you will encounter when talking with assembly experts, so pay extra attention to being precise in your formulations. :)

Comment: I didnt even think about using the stack for this eventhough Im using it all the time for all the "jal" instructions. This works now. I definitely will read through older problems again, this is all just practice, I feel like I slowly start understanding how everything works. Thank you alot for all the help, I really really appreciate that!