# Task: Rewrite X86-assembler program in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm having trouble with a question from my Computer Systems exam testset.

The question/task is: **"Rewrite the following X86-assembler program in C"**.

I have gone through the assembly code, and commented what I think I know:

```
program:
    movq (%rdi), %rax   # 1st argument copied to return value register
    testq %rax, %rax    # Sets ZF to 1 if value stored in it is 0 (return value == 0)?
    je L1               # Jump to L1 if (ZF == 1)
    addq $8, %rdi        # Value 8 is added to 1st argument
    movq %rax, %rdx     # Retun value register is copied to 3rd argument
L3:
    cmpq %rdx, %rax     # sets SF if (return value - 3rd argument < 0)?
    cmovl %rdx, %rax    # Copy 3rd argument to return value register if (SF = 1)?
    addq $8, %rdi        # Value 8 is added to 1st argument
    movq -8(%rdi), %rdx # ?
    testq %rdx, %rdx    # Sets ZF to 1 if value stored in it is 0 (3rd argument == 0)?
    jne L3              # Jump to L3 if (ZF == 0)?
L1:
    ret                 # Pop's return address off the stack, and sets intruction pointer to it
```

There is quiet a few things I am uncertain about, which could be awsome if somebody could clarify for me:

- What is the purpose of `testq %rax, %rax` and `testq %rdx, %rdx`?
- The code make use of `%rdi` (arg1) and `%rdx` (arg3), but not `%rsi` (arg2) - is this to trick us students (no usage for arg2), or how should that be intrepreted when converted to C?
- We never copied anything to the address `-8(%rdi)`, but suddenly we want to copy its content to `%rdx`?

I have been reading up on assembly the entire day, but I am having a really hard time to fully grasp it. If I have made any mistakes in my comments please point them out.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269670/x86-64-assembly-to-c/48269762#48269762 (although you have different questions about the same source)

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48262294/4271923 It's about different CPU (different instructions and registers), but there's my explanation of mental model of CPU vs memory chips, which can be used with x86 in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `test` is used for a zero (`NULL`) check.
2. The argument registers may be used as general purpose. As such, this function only takes 1 argument. `rdx` is just used as a local variable.
3. **You** never set it to anything, but the caller presumably has.

Comment: hmm interesting. With your information I have tried to translate it into the following C code (see answer), but still unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to make a guess as to how it would look in C (thanks to Jesters answer):

```
void main(rdi)
{
    long rax = rdi;

    if (rax == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    rdi += 8;

    long rdx = rdi;

    do 
    {
        if(rdx-rax < 0)
        {
            rax = rdx;

        }

        rdi += 8;
        rdx = unknown_variable //(-8(%rdi))


    } while(rdx != 0 );

    return;

}
```

Am I far off?

Comment: The `rax` itself in your calling convention is very likely used as return value, so your function is not returning `void`, and the `return` statements miss the `rax`, which is being returned. And you are wrong about the first `rax = rdi;`, in C it's more like `rax = *rdi;`, it's loading value from memory, not from register itself, that `rdi` is used as memory address (pointer).

Comment: @Ped7g this and the questions you linked to was just what I needed, thank you very much.